# Image-Link does not work in Slick-Carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

I am trying to make a carousel slider with slick. My Problem is that normal links are working but links with images don´t.

`JSfiddle:` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ka0cvj2/)

I don´t know what could cause this error. maybe I need to activate something in the js script but I couldn't fine anything in the documentation.

Maybe I need to put the image as a backgroundimage. I don't know.

I already searched on google and here but since its a specific script I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed your markup a bit, it seems to work now.
http://jsfiddle.net/8ka0cvj2/2/

I've removed the  tags and the  tags. They have seemed to do the trick.

```
<div class="slider autoplay">

        <a href="tvshow.php?show=howimetyourmother"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/FuBK-Testbild.png"  height="170px" alt="How I Met Your Mother" style="margin:5px" align="left"></a>

        <a href="tvshow.php?show=thebigbangtheory"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/FuBK-Testbild.png"  height="170px" alt="The Big Bang Theory" style="margin:5px" align="left"></a>

        ...
</div>
```